# Redux: Is it always bad practice to keep derived data in the store?

Tags: redux, containers, store

I'm aware of using selectors in Redux, and make use of them. However I have a case where I feel that it would make more sense to store my newly filtered data in the store. Here's my example:

I have an app which displays lots of items. There is a "global filter" option that will only show a certain subset of these items.

The thing is, this filter is global. It changes this list of items across multiple pages and components (e.g. in a table, in a drop down menu). When the filter is set, as far as the whole app is concerned, the current subset is the only list of items that exist.

I could use selectors everywhere necessary but it feels like it would be more robust to just have a 'filteredItems' part of my store. What would be the disadvantage to doing this?

Comment: There are no concepts in redux called selectors.. do you mean reducers? Secondly `it would make more sense to store my newly filtered data in the store` is confusing to read. Could you just make your post a little more clear and accurate?

Comment: This is what I'm referring to: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html

If you know about these concepts, I don't feel that my question is hard to understand.

Comment: I wouldn't use selectors everywhere at all. This would make it very hard to change your code at a later point. I would absolutely store the filtered data into the store (and this is how I do it). You can do this by calling the filter actions against your store.

Comment: It feels to me like selectors are primarily used for enhancing performance around common, repetitive and isolated filters. In order to make your system more robust, I would always centralise the filtered list because it makes a system wide (which is what you need) cache of the filtered data. Selectors are for small isolated caches of data

Comment: Thanks for the input! I guess it's a balance between keeping the store pure vs practical access to derived data.

Comment: Well, I would argue that you could still keep the store pure. I always have a filters section in the store which holds current filters and filtered data. I just see selectors as the small perf enhancers for those common filter/mapping problems in individual components.

Comment: Some would say that storing filtered data in the store means that it is no longer pure. This is because if you are storing the original data, and the filter parameters, the filtered data can be derived. Therefore you have extra information in your store that is not needed. However I think it may not always be practical to think like this...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136152/discussion-between-alexkempton-and-callum-linington).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's up to you to decide what state you have in your app, and where it should live.  Yes, the common advice is to try to keep the store state minimal and use selectors to derive extended values from that, but there's nothing wrong with using reducers to create filtered values that are kept in the state.  Your situation sounds like a perfectly reasonable use case for doing that.

Answer (score 2):

I use selectors ([reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect)) which takes it a step further by caching derived data and other stuff to improve the performance , i use this all the time.

Why?

To keep my components as small and reusable as possible , i noticed that after doing this for while , you start writing your components in a more 'generic' manner, and you use the selectors as kind of plug adapters to shape multiple types of data to fit in a component.

When?

One of the main issue when using reselect , is the setup part , boring... and not without efforts. but when you learn and apply the reselect pattern it will become much simpler to read and maintain a big app

So if you have a lot of computing to do and diversified derived data  , you should pay the price (time , efforts) and set this up  , but if your derived data is small, you should not bother yourself with this.

My two cents

Comment: Yep, selectors are great and I'm using them in parts of this app. My feeling is that as the filtering is happening globally, for data used across entire application, it feels that using selectors aren't suitable. Can you see my dilemma?

Comment: perhaps your filtering should be server-side then

Comment: redconservatory is right , if this is global you should filter your data with the api and then compute , it will be much cleaner , and more efficient